# No carga el scroll del dom al navegar con Link de Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Estoy usando **Link** para navegar entre páginas, sin embargo al navegar entre ellas resulta que no carga el scroll del dom, o sea no puedo ver toda la página completa.

### Página sin scroll

[image]

Ahora bien, si lo pongo desde la url manualmente sí navega normal.

**Adjunto el código**

```
import Link from "next/link";
import headerLinks from "../../models/headerLinks";

export default function SidebarMenu() {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-light fixed-top">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbar" aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar">
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <Link href='/'>
          <a className="navbar-brand">
            <img style={{ height: '60px' }} src="/listica-wp.png" />
          </a>
        </Link>
        <div className="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabIndex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbar" aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel">
          <div className="offcanvas-header">
            <h5 className="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasNavbarLabel">Menu</h5>
            <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div className="offcanvas-body">
            <ul className="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
              {
                headerLinks.map((link, index) => {
                  return (
                    <li key={index} className="nav-item">
                      <Link href={link.url}>
                        <a className="nav-link">
                          {link.name}
                        </a>
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                  )
                })
              }
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```